2D vs 3D Pressure Drag
What is the difference between the parallel component of the drag that depends on alpha for a 2D airfoil and the parallel component of the drag that's on a finite wing?
I understand that for a wing the spanwise flow causes a loss in lift, is this also what causes a parallel component of the pressure differential along the streamwise direction to develop?
The reason I ask is because I've heard people explain that downwash causes this additional pressure drag for 3D wings, but downwash does exist for airfoils too, yet any alpha-dependant drag is bookkept as form drag for 2D airfoils.
I tried avoiding the use of the term, lift-induced drag or the phrase tilting back of the lift vector.
